# deploy vb.net winform native binaries

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, security, source-code-protection

Referencing [this answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9fe9b26f-7318-4bb8-81ac-e28217f3f7cd/which-tool-is-best-for-obfuscation?forum=csharpgeneral), I quote:

> we do not do any obfuscation at all. Instead you might want to check
>   the new possibilities to compile code to native binaries (.Net
>   Native):
>   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn584397%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
>
> Maybe that new feature already offers enough options.

And my question is, is it possible to deploy native binary in end user OS and how to do so if the answer is yes?

Its great if there is such a solution to protect code other than obfuscation.

Answer (score 1):

Currently .Net Native is only available for Universal Windows Platform (UWP), so it cannot be used for projects that target Winform, Wpf...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/net-native/getting-started-with-net-native

Comment: ngen.exe can produce native build for winform; but I don't know how to deploy and run at end machine

Comment: There are third party installers such as Advanced Installer that can ngen assemlies on end user machine.